# How to write a test if React-Error-Boundary recovers from error?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-error-boundary

My application fetches from an `API`, then renders the data. If a non-existing value is inputted, then the `error boundary` triggers and catches the error.

I'm using `ErrorBoundary` from the `react-error-boundary` library and `QueryErrorResetBoundary` from the `react-query` library.

With my `React-Error-Boundary` setup, my application has an `error boundary` trigger when an `error` occurs and is able to recover from the `error` by resetting `state`. I currently have a passing test for the `error boundary` triggering when an `error` occurs. Now I'd like to test if the `error boundary` can recover from the triggered `error boundary` and reset `state`. Please let me know how to go about that with `Jest` and `React Testing Library`.

*App component*

```
const ErrorFallback = ({ error, resetErrorBoundary }) => {
  return (
    <div role="alert">
      <p>Something went wrong:</p>
      <pre style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.message}</pre>
      <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [idQuery, setIdQuery] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <QueryErrorResetBoundary>
        <ErrorBoundary
          FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}
          onReset={() => {
            setIdQuery(0);
          }}
          resetKeys={[idQuery]}
        >
          <Home idQuery={idQuery} setIdQuery={setIdQuery} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </QueryErrorResetBoundary>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={true} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

App.test.js

```
const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)
    return (
        <QueryErrorResetBoundary>
            <ErrorBoundary
                FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}
                onReset={() => {
                    setState(0);
                }}
                resetKeys={[state]}
            >
                <Child />
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </QueryErrorResetBoundary>
    )
}

const Child = () => {
    throw new Error()
}

describe("Error Boundary", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        render(
            <App />
        );
    });

    it("should trigger the Error Boundary when an error occurs", () => {
        const errorMessage = screen.getByTestId("error-boundary-message");
        expect(errorMessage).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it("should recover from Error Boundary", () => {
        // ???
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, I'm suspecting something like this will probably help get you started:

```
const App = () => {
    const [isRecovered,setIsRecovered] = useState(false)
    return (
        <QueryErrorResetBoundary>
            <ErrorBoundary
                FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}
                onReset={() => {
                    setIsRecovered(true)
                }}
                resetKeys={[isRecovered]}
            >
                <Child isRecovered={isRecovered} />
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </QueryErrorResetBoundary>
    )
}

const Child = ({isRecovered}) => {
    if(!isRecovered) throw new Error();
    return 'All Good';
}
```

At the very least you could add the code for `ErrorBoundary` to your question.

Comment: Thank you, @Adam. My apologies, I've edited my question to add a description as well as a sandbox of my code. `ErrorBoundary` is actually from the `React-Error-Boundary` library. You've given me an idea for the test case of "should recover from Error Boundary". Is it correct to test if the `Try Again` button from the `ErrorFallback` was clicked and see if the `isRecovered` state is reset back to `false`?

Comment: @ln09nv2 - yes - you are using the child's `All Good` (or something else you like) to let you know that you have recovered. Alternatively depending on your testing library you could just inspect the state of your component, that's really up to you.